# Why am i getting unexpected token for '<>' error in the following piece of react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting 'unexpected token' error for this code while i am calling this component 'ListEligibilityDataComponent/>' can some one please help me out of this

```
import ListEligibilityDataComponent from './ListEligibilityDataComponent';

class GetDataFromSpringApp extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <>
            <h1>Eligibility Check Application</h1>
            <ListEligibilityDataComponent/>
        </>

        )
    }

}

export default GetDataFromSpringApp
```

Comment: Have you imported react?

Comment: Or React.component ?

Comment: Depending on what version of the transpiler your using it might not have `<>` transformations, either upgrade your transpiler or change -> `<>` to `<React.Fragment>`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import react? You have to import it to use JSX.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use create-react-app you should import React and Component in this way

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
```

on the other hand if you want to use react directly you should import like this

```
<script src="js/reactjs/main.js" type = "text/babel"></script>
```